# More efficient way of managing an online web store

Tags: php, forms, synchronization, store

I am about to start implementing an online web store for a client.  The web store will be constantly receiving new products that will be added into the store's online web catalogue.

My current code design for adding items is a web form where an admin would enter in the name, description, and images of the product.  Each item comes with multiple images both in thumbnail, high resolution, and sometimes 3D rotation (sequence of images).

My main concern with the web form is the uploading of many high resolution images.  Waiting for the upload every time the admin submits a new item really makes it a slow process to add a bunch of new items into the catalogue.  **Is there a better way to build this system other than having a web form?**  Maybe something like an offline system that the admins can just "sync" to the online version.  I don't mind learning something new and coding it myself, but also if there's something on the market already available to buy with similar features I'm all ears.

More info:
I will be the primary developer of this system and I'm only a novice in PHP, Ajax, jQuery, and AS3.  The current website and system is authored in PHP with mySQL.

Comment: So if you were to build a system that synced with the live site, would the user not populate their working copy with a web form too?

Comment: I guess they would, but the working copy would be local so there wouldn't be the long upload times.  I'm hoping to find out if there are any straight forward alternatives for maintaining this type of online catalogue because I know that there's lots of different frameworks or approaches out there that I have no idea about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow the editors to input images as zip files, and a progress bar would be good. You can have an inline upload that just happens when the images are selected, instead of uploading after the form post so that the editors do not feel the waiting effect.

Comment: How would I have the backend extract the images from the zip file and organize them?